# How to show FCM push notifications when app is killed or in background react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-fcm, react-native-push-notification

I am using react-native-FCM and trying to show notifications from the rest client, its working fine when the app is in the foreground and trigger the screen where I want to show the notifications data but when the app is in the background or killed it does not trigger the notifications screen. So, I am wondering how to trigger app notifications screen when the app is killed or in the background.Thanks in advance.Any help would be appreciated.Here is my code:

homepage.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      Platform,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View
    } from 'react-native';

    import FCM,{FCMEvent,RemoteNotificationResult,WillPresentNotificationResult,NotificationType,NotificationActionType,NotificationActionOption,NotificationCategoryOption} from "react-native-fcm";

    let data=[];
    FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async(notify)=>{
      if(notify.local_notification){
        //this is a local notification
      }
      if(notify.opened_from_tray){

            navigation.navigate('TargetScreenPage')


      }
      if(Platform.OS==='android'){
        switch(notify.NotificationType){
          case NotificationType.Remote:
          notify.finish(
            RemoteNotificationResult.NewData  
          )                   
          break;
          case NotificationType.NotificationResponse:
          notify.finish();
          break;
          case NotificationType.WillPresent:
          notify.finish(WillPresentNotificationResult.All)
          break;
        }           
      }
    });
    FCM.on(FCMEvent.RefreshToken,(token)=>{
      console.log(token);
    })



    export default class HomePage extends Component {


      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
          totalTarget: null,
          targetAchieved:null,
          message:null,
          notificationsType:null,
          extraMessage:null,
          token:null
        }
      }

      componentDidMount () {
         const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        FCM.requestPermissions().then(()=>console.log('granted')).catch(()=>console.log('notification permission'))

        FCM.getFCMToken().then(token=>{
          console.log(token)
          this.setState({token:token})
        });

        this.notificationListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async(notify)=>{
          this.setState({
            totalTarget:notify.totalTarget,
            targetAchieved:notify.targetAchieved,
            message:notify.message,
            notificationsType:notify.notificationsType,
            extraMessage:notify.extraMessage
          })
      navigate("TargetScreenPage",{message:this.state.message,extraMessage:this.state.extraMessage})
        })

        FCM.getInitialNotification().then(notify=>{
          console.log("notification-----"+ JSON.stringify(notify))

        })
      }

      componentWillUnmount(){
        this.notificationListener.remove();           
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
           {/* <Text style={styles.instructions}>
              {this.state.token}
            </Text> */}
             <Text style={styles.instructions}>
              {this.state.totalTarget}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
              {this.state.targetAchieved}
            </Text>

             <Text style={styles.instructions}>
              {this.state.message}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.instructions}>
              {this.state.notificationsType}
            </Text>
         <Text style={styles.instructions}>
              {this.state.extraMessage}
            </Text>

          </View>                                                       
        );
      }
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
      },
      welcome: {
        fontSize: 40,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
      },
      instructions: {
        fontSize:40,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
        flexDirection:'row'
      },              
    });
```

and TargetScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {ImageBackground,
  Platform,StyleSheet,BackHandler,Image,TouchableOpacity,Text,StatusBar,View} from 'react-native';
import { Header,Right} from 'native-base';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class TargetScreen extends Component {

    handleCrossButtonClick() {
        this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
        return true;
    }                      

  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return (
    <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
    <StatusBar hidden = {true} />
    <Header style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff" ,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Image style={{height:45,width:90,resizeMode: "stretch",marginLeft:95}} source={require('./images/salesLineLogo.jpg')} />
        <Right>      
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.handleCrossButtonClick()}>
        <Image style={{height:25,width:25,resizeMode: "stretch"}} source={require('./images/cross.png')}/>      
        </TouchableOpacity></Right>               
     </Header>        
     <View style={{flex:0.5,justifyContent:'center',alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <ImageBackground source={require('./images/up-arrow.png')} style={{ resizeMode: "stretch",height: 95, width: 95,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center' }} >
    <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>8</Text></ImageBackground>
    <Text style={{fontSize:20,marginTop:25}}>{params.message}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex:0.5,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
    <ImageBackground source={require('./images/up-arrow.png')} style={{ resizeMode: "stretch",height: 95, width: 95,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}} >
    <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>8</Text></ImageBackground> 
    <Text style={{fontSize:20,marginTop:25}}>{params.extraMessage}</Text>
    </View></View>               
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49490729/7651600)

Comment: same issue, did you find solution?